# Coordinates and graphics

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, coordinate

> Make a line in 3D that goes through 50 random points with integer coordinates randomly chosen up to 50.

```
Graphics3D[
 Line[
  Table[RandomInteger[c, 3], {c, 50}]]]
```

```
Graphics3D[
 Point[
  Table[RandomInteger[c, 3], {c, 50}]]]
```

> How to combine these two plots into one? plz help.
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Graphics3D[{Line[#], Point[#]}] &[Table[RandomInteger[c, 3], {c, 50}]]
```

[image]

Comment: but it shows incorrect. this question (qst no:14.10) is from Stephen wolfram: an elementary introduction to wolfram language course on the topic ** "coordinates and graphics question no 14.10" **.  link to the page:[Link] (https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/an-elementary-introduction-to-the-wolfram-language/14-coordinates-and-graphics.en.html)

Comment: @Ratheesh What means "but it shows incorrect"?

Answer (score 2):

```
ListLinePlot3D[RandomInteger[50, {50, 3}], PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 PlotMarkers -> Point, Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> False]
```

[image]